# c# запустить несколько Task"ов с разными значениями

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста. Мне нужно запустить несколько Task"ов с разными значениями, как это можно реализовать ? Перепробовал множество способов запуска Task, но пока в рабочем потоке принимается значение, в основном потоке уже меняется итерация, и значения не совпадают

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

   Task[] tasks = new Task[memberscount];
     for (int i = 0; i < memberscount; i++)
            {
                string login = accounts[acc];
                acc++;
                string password = accounts[acc];
                acc++;
                var count = i;
               tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Mytt(models, proxy[count], login, password, count)); //Как сделать, чтобы здесь передалось текущее значение count???
        }
```

Пока происходит запуск Таска, count уже равняется 3

Даже когда я запускаю только один поток
в методе Mytt, count уже равняется 1, а не 0.
Или можно ли как то подождать, пока не запуститься Task?

Comment: ну так получите `proxy[count]` в переменную перед запуском таска, и скормите полученное значение в метод.

Comment: Проверьте сам метод Mytt получше, с count в цикле у вас вроде всё нормально.

Comment: Думаю, дело в том, что потоки запускаются не в том порядке, в котором вы ожидаете. Значения передаются верные. Просто второй поток (с i=1) может стартовать раньше первого (с i=0) и т. п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно разделить блок на два цикла:  в первом заполнить массив tasks, а во-втором запустить каждый task последовательно.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[memberscount];
for (int i = 0; i < memberscount; i++)
{
    string login = accounts[acc];
    acc++;
    string password = accounts[acc];
    acc++;
    var count = i;
    tasks[i] = new Task(() => Mytt(models, proxy[count], login, password, count));
}

foreach (var task in tasks)
    task.Start();
```